# You make a plan, but the world have the other

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to know which one of these sentences is more acceptable?

1. You make a plan, but the world have the other.
2. You made a plan, but the world have the other.

Comment: Any more context? Seems like this should be in the past tense rather than present (since it seems to reach a conclusion). I would prefer "You made a plan, but the world had a different one."

Answer (score 1):

> You made a plan, but the world has another.

The world is treated as a third-person singular.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have the other better way to express the same meaning?

Comment: While you are making your plans, life comes up with its own ones.